# Django Application Using GMAIL API, Oauth Token Deleted Error

Tags: python, django, oauth, gmail-api

I am currently trying to create an application in Django that fetches emails from an Inbox using the gmail API. I was able to successfully perform this in Nodejs, but I wanted to switch to using Django. I used the Python Gmail API quickstart: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python. I created a view for the function found in the tutorial and the first issue I encountered was "invalid redirect uri" which is an issue I encountered in the past, which I still don't understand. I tried editing the redirect uris in the Oauth Token to fix this issue, but it didn't work (I probably was doing it wrong). Eventually, I deleted the Oauth Token and tried creating a new GCP project but it said "Oauth Token deleted". I kept trying to create new ones (I updated the credentials.json everytime). I even tried starting a new Django project with a new GCP Project+ Oauth token, but I'm still getting the same "Oauth Token Deleted" error. I'm not sure whats going wrong and was wondering if someone with experience using the API would know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: break your problem into parts! First, have you confirmed that the quickstart.py works? Dong so confirms that you problem isn't with the gmail api, but with your Django project and how you've set up your views.

Comment: So I know it isnt a view issue because it effectively executes the quickstart.py script. The errors that I am getting are from google, not Django.

Comment: Ok, then you need to supply us with the exact errors you're getting back from the google API.  Maybe your google api token isn't being accepted? or being passed correctly? etc.